# Select count of specific rows within WHERE clause in a Postgres SELECT statement

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, psql

Let's say I have a table called Build and a table called Test. Now, for every build there are 3 tests. And the table tests has build_id as foreign key. Also, when a test fails my test framework retries the test again. Given this, there would be atleast 3 entries in the Test table + more based on how many tests failed and how many times it was retries (max = 3). Also, after retries, if the test passes, then the test is marked as passed.

```
Sample:
Build Table:
Id     No of Tests     Failure Count
1            3                     0
2            3                     0
3            3                     1


Tests Table: 
build_id        test_id       test_name     test_result
1                      1                test1                p
1                      2                test2                p
1                      3                test3                f
1                      3                test3                f
1                      3                test3                f
1                      3                test3                p
2                      1                test1                p
2                      2                test2                p
2                      3                test3                p
3                      1                test1                p
3                      2                test2                f
3                      3                test3                p
2                      2                test2                f
2                      2                test2                f
2                      2                test2                f
```

Now, based on that I want to print

```
test_name    retries         
test3           3                    
test2           3
```

Comment: Not really clear what you want. It seems a simple count with an where clause (maybe a having count). Pretty straightforward, what have you tried to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of times that a test is "f":

```
select test_name, count(*) as retries
from tests
where test_result = 'f'
group by test_name;
```